# how to split one dimentional array returned by numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, import

I am using the below code to read an array from a csv file.

```
na_orders = np.loadtxt(orders_file, delimiter=',', skiprows=0,dtype='i4,i4,i4,S5,S4,f4')
```

this return a one dimentional

```
[(2011, 1, 10, 'A', 'B', 1500.0) (2011, 1, 13, 'A', 'S', 1500.0)
 (2011, 1, 13, 'I', 'B', 4000.0) (2011, 1, 26, 'G', 'B', 1000.0)
 (2011, 2, 2, 'X', 'S', 4000.0) (2011, 2, 10, 'X', 'B', 4000.0)
 (2011, 3, 3, 'G', 'S', 1000.0) (2011, 3, 3, 'I', 'S', 2200.0)
 (2011, 6, 3, 'I', 'S', 3300.0) (2011, 5, 3, 'I', 'B', 1500.0)
 (2011, 6, 10, 'AL', 'B', 1200.0) (2011, 8, 1, 'G', 'B', 55.0)
 (2011, 8, 1, 'G', 's', 55.0) (2011, 12, 20, 'A', 'S', 1200.0)]
```

I want a 2d array that will split each one of the elements into different columns

Comment: If you work with different types of data, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) might be a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dtype=object` constructor:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [(2011, 1, 10, 'A', 'B', 1500.0), ..., (2011, 12, 20, 'A', 'S', 1200.0),]
>>> a = np.array(l, dtype='object')
>>> a
array([[2011, 1, 10, A, B, 1500.0],
...
       [2011, 12, 20, A, S, 1200.0]], dtype=object)
>>> a.shape
(14, 6)
>>> sum(a[:, -1])
26510.0
```

Such an array will not be as efficient as an array of primitive values, but it will support all operations normally supported by numpy arrays, while still providing for different types in different columns.